# fixing version problems in bower after installing Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, bower, angularjs-material

I have a project which was using angular version 1.4. I installed `angular material` via bower and then subsequently received the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info is not a function
```

I read this was to do with the version of angular I'm using so I updated angular and then `angular-animate` to 1.6. However this didn't fix the problem. I tried running `bower update` but I still have the above error.

When I ran bower update I received the following warning...

```
Resort to using angular#~1.4.2 which resolved to angular#1.4.14
Code incompatibilities may occur.
```

this is the contents of my `bower.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "node-template",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": [
    "./public/styles/*.css",
    "./public/scripts/*.js"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-animate": "1.6",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.4.2",
    "angular-messages": "~1.4.2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.5",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "angular": "1.6",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~2.5.0",
    "angular-google-chart": "~0.1.0",
    "velocity": "~1.4.2",
    "animate.css": "~3.5.2",
    "angular-file-saver": "~1.1.3",
    "ng-file-upload": "~12.2.13",
    "ng-img-crop": "ngImgCrop#~0.3.2",
    "angularfire": "~2.3.0",
    "angular-material": "~1.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.4.2"
  },
  "overrides": {},
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "angular": "~1.4.2"
  }
}
```

Is bower telling me I'm using version 1.4? I don't understand why it cannot resolve the version problems I'm encountering?

Edit:

here is my new bower.json after upgrading to angular 1.5:

```
{
  "name": "node-template",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": [
    "./public/styles/*.css",
    "./public/scripts/*.js"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-animate": "1.4",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.4.2",
    "angular-messages": "~1.4.2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.5",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "angular": "1.5",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~2.5.0",
    "angular-google-chart": "~0.1.0",
    "velocity": "~1.4.2",
    "animate.css": "~3.5.2",
    "angular-file-saver": "~1.1.3",
    "ng-file-upload": "~12.2.13",
    "ng-img-crop": "ngImgCrop#~0.3.2",
    "angularfire": "~2.3.0",
    "angular-material": "~1.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.4.2"
  },
  "overrides": {},
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "angular": "1.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Angular 1.4.14 installed. Looking at the [bower.json](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/package.json) for Angular Material the minimum version of AngularJS required for the package is 1.5 which is probably why you are having errors. Can you not update to AngularJS 1.5?

Failing that, I suggest you install an older version of Angular Material that is compatible with 1.4.x

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated to angular version 1.5. Bower gave me a message saying 'unable to find a suitable version for angular', I picked one of the options which said 1.5. I then tried to install `angular-material` again and had to pick a suitable version for angular again. Then I ran the project but I still get the original error saying `angular.module(...).info is not a function`

Comment: Also, just to check, you have included Angular in your html havent you?

Comment: Please see the updated bower.json. I use a gulp task to pull Angular from my `bower_components` folder and this gets concatenated and included in my html file.

Comment: I tend to find you need to run ALL your Angular components at the same version else you can get problems, try that? i.e. angular-sanitize and angular-messages are still 1.4.2

Comment: I tried updating the other components that were at 1.4.2, but I still get the same error message. I was really hoping that using `bower` would help solve these kinds of version issues.

Answer (score 0):

The error I was seeing...

```
angular.module(...).info is not a function
```

...seems to arise when the version of `angular-aria` (required by `angular-material`) is newer than the version of `angular`. I managed to get my build working again by setting `angular-aria` to be the same version as angular.